# limited company as tax vehicle for renting out flats as addition to day job?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, austria

This is a more theoretical question to find out if I understood it correctly. I think to answering the question it is irrelevant where I have to pay taxes since it's more of a number game.

### Information

I have to pay taxes in Austria. Personal income-tax on salary (and rentals income combined) depends on the amount you make. The percentage is higher the more you make. For example [20%, 30%, 41%, 48%, 50%](https://www.finanz.at/steuern/lohnsteuertabelle/)

If you found a limited company it has to pay a corporate-tax of 25%. If you take money out of the company you have to pay additional capital-gains-tax of 27.5% which combined is 45.625%. However if you leave it in the company you only have to pay 25% (but get no money out). You could also pay a salary to yourself, which would be subjected to the personal income-tax mentioned in the first paragraph and additional to insurance and so on -> really bad idea.

There are additional cost for limited companies, this would be one time payments to found it and regular ones like bookkeeping (double entry) and publishing the yearly results,...

### Question

I want to **reinvest all** my money gained from renting out flats (or other business ideas) to get compound interest and take something out later (about 10-20years) when I need it (while then paying combined ~45%).

My question is if my personal tax class is for example 45% any they company is only paying 25% corporate-tax would it make sense to found one? The one condition which must be fulfilled in my eyes is that the additional reoccurring costs have to be (way) less then the tax savings. (and I have to have a regular job being taxed at about 41%)

e.g annual revenue of 8k would be taxed at 2k (25%) or 3.28k (41%) so the additional fixed costs must be lower than 1.28k to start making sense.

Comment: Leaving aside the question about whether to incorporate - have you run any numbers about what the costs and revenue associated with renting flats in your area would be? In many cases, net rental income for even a moderately successful investment might be Nil, with the future gains to be realized on eventually selling the properties. This will be incredibly jurisdiction and time-period dependent. If it would be true for you, then you have minimal rental income to defer. You assume annual revenue of 8k - but what would the 'taxable income' of that be? [I am not familiar with Austrian taxes].

Comment: with 8k revenue I meant taxable income (sorry translation mistake). I already own the house the flats are not renovated yet, but will be the next 5 years - depends on my time. The 8k are from my current income streams which are not form my job and would otherwise be taxed with my income-tax. From a juristical standpoint I would be a "commercial landlord" and not private anyway since its more than 4 flats. If i would not own the house already renovating an renting out would be a negative game since flats can only be tax deducted over 66years

Comment: Austrian here - keep in mind that: Up to rental income of 30,000 euros per year there is no VAT liability. If rental income exceeds this value, landlords are automatically considered small business owners. As a result, sales tax must also be paid to the tax office. -> [Link](https://www.finanz.at/immobilien/mieteinnahmen/#:~:text=Bis%20zu%20Mieteinnahmen%20in%20H%C3%B6he,das%20Finanzamt%20abgef%C3%BChrt%20werden%20muss.)

Comment: A friend of a friend gave me the tip to opt-in for vat anyway to get "cheaper" bills for renovation materials and therefor also lower opportunity or credit cost. I really like the idea, however it will make bookkeeping more expensive hence I even more tend to the gmbh. also I'm near the income of 30k which could be over 30k cause by inflation by the time the renovations are finished.

Comment: @Fritz The fact that you already own the land personally is likely a significant complication. In some countries, for you to transfer ownership from yourself to your corporation, you would need to recognize some form of a gain on the increase in value since your purchase [or other similar adjustments]. No idea if this is the case for Austria.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I would not transfer the ownership, I just would rent it out to my own company (which is also tax relevant for my personal income-tax since the rate must be comparable to a rate someone else would get). A real estate agent told me that if I rent it out to my company before renovation I could set low rent and then do the renovation inside the company and deduct taxes there. New properties and so on will be owned by the company to escape taxes for changing ownership. In Austria you have to pay for transfres and additional for gain (if any)

Comment: @Fritz Talk to a tax advisor, not a realtor [who is not a tax expert, and does not have your interests at heart]. The idea that you could rent something out to the Corp for less than it rents it out to a 3rd party would be at least holding hands with tax avoidance in most jurisdictions I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm on the beginning of my journey -  talked to an ex tax advisor who advised that my plan is to small to make sense for a company. However in my excel it starts making sense at 8k and therefore I'm looking for some logic errors. I will for sure go to a paid advisor before I take the next step.